# Security Review Step 5 issue

Tags: managed-package, security-review, developer

I've reached Step 5 of the Security Review submission for my new Managed Package. I've created a new Developer Org, installed the package and then proceeded to continue with the review.

At step 5, when adding the test org info, the "loading" just keeps going for hours and doesn't give any feedback.

Step 5 - Test Environments
Security Review for XXX (Spring 2014 / 1.2.0)

I'm probably doing something wrong and was wondering if someone could help me figure out what it is.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is a bug in the web page wizard, I've not encountered this before, it usually goes smoothly. Have you tried using another browser? If so, it's possible its a bug and you may need to report it to Salesforce. I'd recommend you raise a Salesforce case via your Partner Portal login.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm still stuck after trying this in Chrome, Firefox and IE. I've created a case on the Partner Portal to see if they can send me some feedback on this, thanks for your help.